# How to interact with an SVG asset in an offline Progressive Web App?

Tags: svg, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a PWA with VueJs and the latest Google workbox. As you can see [here](https://khmer-typing.passerellesnumeriques.org/), the service  worker does its job and cache the SVG files used in my application. LightHouse gives me the full score in the PWA section and I can install and use the application online.

However, when I am offline the parts using an SVG asset don’t work and display a fallback message, i.e. this [code](https://github.com/passerelles-numeriques/khmer-typing/blob/master/src/renderer/components/VisualKeyboard/VisualKeyboard.vue#L43) doesn’t load the asset and display *Your browser doesn't support SVG*:

```
          <object
            data="static/svg/Khmer_unicode_NiDA_layout.svg"
            type="image/svg+xml"
            id="keyboard-vk">Your browser doesn't support SVG</object>
```

It doesn’t work on Google and Firefox. If read well the [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#implementer-concerns), it is because the fetch algorithm uses the network for OBJECT and EMBED tags to load the asset whether or not it is on the same origin (for security concerns?).

What are my alternatives as we can’t interact with the SVG object by using an IMG tag.

Answer (score 0):

After many tests and some search, I do confirm that `object` and `embed` tags with a `src` attribute must be avoided in a progressive web application. Because, for obscure reasons, the specifications say (although it is not normative) that browsers should attempt to download the assets by the network without trying to fetch the cache first. Even if the asset is into the same location. Then if you're offline the application cannot work.

The best think to do is to inline the SVG content (i.e. copy/paste or include into the HTML page) if you want to interact with the SVG elements.